# Android studio NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1 error

Tags: android, android-studio

Earlier my android studio worked properly, but now it doesn't. [This is how my android studio looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmlm3.png), I've tried many solutions in stack overflow regarding this question, but they didn't work for me, please if someone can help me I highly appreciate it, I'm new to android.

Comment: use lower version than 24.0.1, you will find it in folder: path \sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way to solve this is to update you gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 24

targetSdkVersion 24
```

**Also be sure you update your Android SDK as well.**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I used my smart phone to run my apps instead of using emulator, My phone's version is 19. So I keep targetSdkVersion as 19. Are there another solutions?

Comment: you can set minSdkVersion 19 and upgrade targetSdkVersion to 24 safely. that would keep your app available for your device (API-19) and helps you to get support of appcomp‌​at-v7

Answer (score 0):

your compileSdkVersion is less than 24.

go to bottom path:

"your sdk location"/platforms

for example you may see the bottom folder:

android-27

it's means my platform version is 27.goto gradle.build(module:app) and set compileSdkVersion to your version of platform. for example in my case:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```